# Can I delete the tvOS from react native project?

Tags: javascript, react-native, xcode9

Eventually, I will be submitting a react native app to the app store but the app will only run on iOS, not tvOS. Will I be able to delete these targets and stuff and submit the project with no problem?
[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it can be deleted. You wont have any problem submitting it to the app store.

Comment: Well i tried to do that and xcode totally crashed and i am unable to open the project again, this is actually a really bad idea

Comment: Tried that and the whole thing just blew up to my face, weee

Comment: I had to delete the "*-tvOSTests" target first before deleting the actual tvOS target, otherwise XCode would crash.

Comment: might also need to remove that from the Podfile

Comment: I deleted Tests first and xcode still crashed when I went to delete the tvOS target

Answer (score 21):

Yes you can delete it but first delete `appName-tvOSTests` then delete `appName-tvOS` (otherwise xcode will crash).
After that remove this code from `ios/Podfile` :

```rb
target 'appName-tvOS' do
  # Pods for appName-tvOS

  target 'appName-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```